# Writer document showing text overlap

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I've imported a Microsoft .doc file into LibreOffice Writer, however some of the headings aren't being displayed correctly. Is there a way around this?

[image: LibreOffice Writer display]

Comment: Is everything there definitely all text? The title 'City Centre Hospital - Birmingham' isn't an image is it?

Comment: It's all text, just text with different styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to re-define the heading paragraph styles. Maybe just re-assigning the paragraph styles does the trick; if it doesn't, you will have to remove "direct formatting" first (right-lick on the heading and select the topmost context menu entry).